# Control-case study with Multiple Regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, case-control-study

I want to fit a multiple linear regression to a population composed by two groups, one is the control group, and the other one is the group subjected to a treatment.

The independent variables are both categorical and continuos.

What I did is this:

```
mod <- lm( Y ~ as.factor(Groups) + X1 + X2 + ... + Xn)
```

where Groups = Control, Treatment.

But how can compare the treatment group with respect to the control?

Comment: You wrote "The dependent variables are both categorical and continuous", so are you fitting separate regression models for each dependent variable? In any case, if you recode your "Groups" variable as a binary predictor, you can interpret the regression coefficient accordingly. Beyond that it is not really clear what you mean by compare in this context?

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo. I meant independent not dependent. Of course the response (Y) is only continuos.

Comment: Your model is assuming that the only difference between treatment and control is in the intercept.  If some of the control variables $X_1,X_2,\dotsc,X_n$  could act differently in the two groups, you need interactions.